# Django test VS pytest

Tags: python, django, pytest, django-unittest, pytest-django

I am new to django `unittest` and `pytest`. However, I started to feel that `pytest` test case is more compact and clearer.

Here is my test cases:

```
class OrderEndpointTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        user = User.objects.create_superuser(username='admin', password='password', email='pencil@gmail.com')
        mommy.make(CarData, _quantity=1)
        mommy.make(UserProfile, _quantity=1, user=user)

    def test_get_order(self):
        mommy.make(Shop, _quantity=1)
        mommy.make(Staff, _quantity=1, shop=Shop.objects.first())
        mommy.make(Order, _quantity=1, car_info={"color": "Black"}, customer={"name": "Lord Elcolie"},
                   staff=Staff.objects.first(), shop=Shop.objects.first())

        factory = APIRequestFactory()
        user = User.objects.get(username='admin')
        view = OrderViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})

        request = factory.get('/api/orders/')
        force_authenticate(request, user=user)
        response = view(request)
        assert 200 == response.status_code
        assert 1 == len(response.data.get('results'))
```

And here is the `pytest` version

```
def test_get_order(car_data, admin_user, orders):
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    user = User.objects.get(username='admin')
    view = OrderViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})

    request = factory.get('/api/orders/')
    force_authenticate(request, user=user)
    response = view(request)
    assert 200 == response.status_code
    assert 1 == len(response.data.get('results'))
```

The benefit from `pytest` is `fixture` in another file. It makes my test case compact by let them be my input parameters.

Are they any benefit of using Django `unittest` than `pytest`?

**Update: 1July2017**
**Update: 5July2017**
**Update: 1Sep2017**
**Update: 29Sep2017**
**Update: 26Dec2017**

1. Pytest reduces your problem when fixtures got mutated over the test.
   I got `testcases` that run individually passed, but fail when run
   thoroughly.
2. Pytest will show you the assertion output if the error occur. Django
   unittest does not. I have to put the breakpoint on my own and
   investigate the error.
3. Pytest allow you to use real database with simple decorator. Django
   test does not. You have to create your own customized command for
   your job
4. Pytest is generic. Being an generic it means you feel comfortable to 
   work with project outside the Django. For example when you have to 
   build micro-service such as Flask + 3rd parties like APScheduler, 
   PyRad, ... etc. I mention this because my backend life uses Django 50%
   The rest of the is `Python` and infra
5. Pytest is not using multiple inheritance to create my fixtures
6. Unittest takes advantage on `gitlab-ci` over Pytest when used with `Docker` as a runner by smoothly execute without any extra configurations. [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966456/docker-runner-pytest-does-not-collect-testcases)

Comment: Django tests do support fixtures. Just saying...

Comment: @spectras Hi. please correct if my information is outdated. I really want to know and choose right tools for right situation. Right now I do both of them base on project leader. If I lead I use `pytest`. The others use `Django test` I do follow it. Therefore I am start the question on here and discuss.

Comment: I create fixtures in the method `setUp()` and reuse by inheritance. Are you talking on the same fixtures?

Comment: No, I'm talking about [Django fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have not use it because I can not use it with `mommy`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904245/reset-sequence-in-pytest-django I am unable to find `reset_transaction` in `pytest`. After certain time I will put it here and it might change my mind!

Comment: By the way, `mommy.make` returns created instance. So this code is cleaner `shop = mommy.make(Shop, _quantity=1); mommy.make(Staff, _quantity=1, shop=shop)`

Answer (score 10):

i've used Django test for my entire life and now i am using Py.test. I agree that pytest is much cleaner than django itself.

> The benefit from pytest is fixture in another file. It makes my test case compact by let them be my input parameters.

In Django unittest you can still use fixtures in other file by using the attribute `fixtures = ['appname/fixtures/my_fixture.json']`

> Pytest will show you the assertion output if the error occur. Django unittest does not. I have to put the breakpoint on my own and investigate the error.

Did you tried to change the `--verbose` param on `python manage.py tests`?

A few tips:

1. There is a package called `pytest-django` that will help you integrate and using django with pytest.
2. I think that if you use classes will you not need to use the `factory = APIRequestFactory()`, the test methods itself they have a parameter called `client` that is a interface to the python `requests` module to access your views.

   ```
   import pytest

   from model_mommy import mommy

   @pytest.fixture()
   def user(db):
       return mommy.make(User)

   class SiteAPIViewTestSuite:
       def test_create_view(self, client, user):
           assert Site.objects.count() == 0

           post_data = {
               'name': 'Stackoverflow'
               'url': 'http://stackoverflow.com',
               'user_id': user.id,
           }
           response = client.post(
               reverse('sites:create'),
               json.dumps(post_data),
               content_type='application/json',
           )

           data = response.json()
           assert response.status_code == 201
           assert Site.objects.count() == 1
           assert data == {
               'count': 1,
               'next': None,
               'previous': None
               'results': [{
                   'pk': 1,
                   'name': 'Stackoverflow',
                   'url': 'http://stackoverflow.com',
                   'user_id': user.id
               }]
           }
   ```

Comment: +1 Thank you for sharing your experience with me. I had tried `fixture.json`. It is not flexible. `model_mommy` is fit for my need. For `--verbose` this is my bad. I did't know about this. Your given example on `client` is clean! Let me try it with incoming project.

Comment: I also use `model_mommy`, its awesome and work fine.

Comment: Instead of fixtures I prefer factories with [factory_boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I also use those to generate some test data (faker built in) during development.

Comment: Model Mommy is no longer maintained and was replaced by [Model Bakery](https://pypi.org/project/model-bakery/).

Comment: At first glance pytest is tempting and you write fancy fixtures. At the end those fixtures will haunt you if do not do the teardown properly. You will end up having flaky tests. Your CI/CD pipeline will be stalled and you will spend more time fixing those fixtures and teardown book keeping. And that's a nasty task.

Comment: My advice after years of experience with pytest and Unittest, I recommend Django unittest with FactoryBoy. At the beginning it looks "awesome" but at the end it's not "aweosme"

Answer (score 0):

I am all for using PyTest to test any Python project including Django projects.

I just want to address the point 6 in your list:

> 6. unittest takes advantage on gitlab-ci over Pytest when used with Docker as a runner by smoothly execute without any extra
>    configurations...

Maybe you should take a look at [tox](https://tox.wiki/en/4.11.4/) and at docker images that has `tox` installed and ready to run such as https://hub.docker.com/r/plone/test-with-tox

---