# reset_sequence in pytest-django

Tags: python, django, pytest

I have posted my question to the [pytest-django](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/issues). But it seems non-active at least 2 weeks. I decided to ask my question here.

In my test I want to use [reset_sequence=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.reset_sequences). 
How to do that in `pytest-django`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In latest pytest-django 3.8.0, you can do `@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True,reset_sequences=True)` to use **reset_sequences**. You can find it in [this](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html) official documentation